# Is "say to X" grammatically correct but not colloquial?

Tags: word-usage, prepositions, korean

So I'm living in South Korea and nearly everyone who is conversational in English says "say to X" instead of "tell X."  For some reason, they avoid using "tell X" or "told X" and they stick to "say to X" and "said to X" when making *statements*, which to me doesn't sound colloquial (and perhaps grammatically incorrect). Furthermore, they always feel the need to add "me" when using "say" or "said" when the statement was made to them.

For instance

> "Say to John he needs to be here by 9:00 p.m." (instead of "tell
> John...")
>
> "John said to me he loves me" (instead of "John said..." or "John told me...")
>
> "John said to Alice he loves her "  (instead of "John told Alice...")

They also use the "to" preposition in other instances when it is not necessary.

To me, "say/ said" should be used in *statements* only when quoting something that was said to the speaker. So adding "to me" to "say/said" is completely superfluous. Also, "say/said" shouldn't be used to quote something that wasn't said directly to the speaker.

Are the examples above grammatically correct but not colloquial?  If not, what is the appropriate grammar rule to cite?

Thanks for the help.

Comment: If "everyone here" uses these constructions it would seem to follow that they are perfectly good Korean English. I don't think we have a tag for that--yet--though I have added the existing tag "Korean."

Comment: I meant to say "everyone who is conversational in English" I will make the edits.

Comment: What makes you think they have to use **tell**? Is there something wrong with the verb **say**? Call to John is an entirely different issue and you need to capitalize **john**.

Comment: In my opinion, as a colloquial matter, when one is making a statement, the use of say should only be used to quote something that was told to the speaker.  For instance, "he said he'll be here at 3" (it's implied that what was said was to the speaker) or "John told me (said) Sally had said she would be here by 5."    It is very common for a native Korean who speaks English as a second language to say "Sally said to me she would be here at 5", which sounds incredibly strange to me.

Comment: The reason I asked you the question in the comment was I wanted to guide you to write a more *on-topic* question. You should have specified that reason. Then users understand why you are asking this question.

Comment: Your edition created more confusion. You need to write full sentences to see whether it is a direct speech or indirect speech (reported speech) i.e. John said to me, "I love you." Is there anything wrong with this sentence? Your examples don't work. And you didn't specify the reason that you posted in your comment. This question doesn't work.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because not only is the question unclear, but the question is primarily opinion-based without proper research or full example sentences.

Comment: The question is not primarily opinion-based.  Firstly, most native speakers would agree that the use of "say" in the above sentences sound highly unusual.  It is a common observation amongst native English teachers who teach English in South Korea.  Secondly, I've tried to find sentences online using "say/said" in the ways exampled above.  I've come up with nothing; the uses are clearly not colloquial.  Now, just because I can't find a sentence or a rule saying one way or another on the issue, it doesn't mean its grammatically incorrect/correct.  I came here to find a clear definitive answer.

Comment: If South Koreans use "say to" instead of "tell", then "say to" is correct in South Korean English. If English is going to be a global language, then native speakers have to let go of the idea that 'what native speakers say' is the measure of right or wrong. I agree with Rathony - the question is unanswerable as it stands. Voting to close.

Comment: South Korean English isn't English.  Would you advise a South Korean student to keep saying "discuss about" or "call to" or "give to X the pencil" because it's how they've been taught at school?  They also believe cheating is called cunning and a part time job is called an adebyte.  In order one to be an English speaker, one must be able to articulate oneself to native English speakers.  They should start with the basics.  Since when is word choice not relevant or not in the control of native English speakers?

Comment: "So I say to myself, 'Self, you need to spend less time on EL&U and more time doing something useful.'"

Answer (score 1):

No, "say to X" is fine.  It is OK in formal speech as well as colloquial speech.  We can find it in Shakespeare, for example.

> Shall I say to Caesar
>   What you require of him?

--Anthony and Cleopatra: III, 13

Comment: Using Shakespeare to demonstrate a particular word usage or phrasing is colloquial is specious.

Comment: Also, the question pertains to declarative statements and not questions.

Answer (score 0):

"Say to X" is colloquial in casual and everyday conversation. The sentence is definitely understood and from experience I have heard the use of "X said to me" or "X said to Y" or "I said to X". However, I have not heard "Say to X" as often, but regardless it is used. Personally to me, it sounds a bit odd to say "Say to X" because usually say "Tell it to X" and less commonly "Say it to X".

Long story short, yes, it makes sense, and no, it is colloquial.

Comment: "Say to X" is only colloquial when used in a _question_.  What did you say to me? or What did he say to you?  I've only heard it in _declarative statements_ when people fumble their words.  So in a declarative sentence, the use of "Say to X" is not colloquial. Colloquial means it sounds natural, not that it is understood or used here and there.